# Type hinting Generic Class with Fallback types

Tags: generics, type-hinting, mypy, python-3.10

Consider the following example

```py
from typing import Generic, Optional, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", int, tuple[int, ...])
S = TypeVar("S", int, tuple[int, ...])


class Foo(Generic[S, T]):
    fallback_int: S
    fallback_tuple: T

    def __init__(self, x: Optional[S] = None, y: Optional[T] = None):
        if x is None:
            # Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "Tuple[int, ...]")
            self.fallback_int = 0  
        else:
            self.fallback_int = x

        if y is None:
            # Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[]", variable has type "int")
            self.fallback_tuple = () 
        else:
            self.fallback_tuple = y
```

I understand why `mypy` raises the error, as in both code-paths, either then `T` is `int` or when  `T` is `tuple[int, ...]`, the type of `Foo.x` must be equal to `T`.

How can I properly type hint `Foo` to avoid this error?

Comment: Why does `T` need to be `TypeVar("T", int, tuple[int, ...])` over `Union[int, tuple[int, ...]]`? Same for `S`.